# GDPR: encyption at-rest instead of data lookup tables

Tags: architecture, etl, data-warehouse, gdprconsentform

Encryption at-rest - is storing data inside your storage/database in encrypted format. During processing you need to decrypt data every time, calculate something and then encrypt everything back (encryption is managed by storage).

*Does encryption at-rest resolve "right to be forgotten" issue? When you can't go with encryption at-rest and should choose [data lookup tables](https://www.compuware.com/data-lookup-table/) and pseudo-anonymization?*

Unlike [data lookup tables](https://www.compuware.com/data-lookup-table/), encryption at-rest is much easier to implement. It can affect your performance though, and maybe billing.

AFAIK due to GDPR, you shouldn't stop processing or remove anonymized data. In other hand, ETL jobs must have permissions to decrypt data. Means everyone who has privileges to run a job (i.e. developer, data scientist or QA) will still be able to decrypt (de-anonymize) the data with encryption key.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If encryption is occurring at the storage layer then it does not help with the right to be forgotten. If you want to use encryption to solve the right to be forgotten challenge, then I would suggest using a unique encryption key per data subject. If a data subject needs to be forgotten, you can then delete your copy of the encryption key and you have effectively "crypto-shredded" all the data that is protected by that key. For this to work best you would need to carefully design your architecture (e.g. can you keep the key separate to the data, so that it isn't backed-up and find another way to ensure availability of current keys in a DR scenario etc).

A data lookup table is the equivalent of a tokenization service, where you're replacing a data subject's name or other details with a token. By deleting (or altering) the token in the data lookup table you have removed the ability to resolve the token back to the actual data subject. This would provide a lesser degree of assurance as to the level of "forgotten-ness" that had been achieved as you might still be able to identify a data subject indirectly through other information about them. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-anonymity to understand this concept in-depth.

Comment: thanks for great answer! Looks like with millions of users encryption-at-rest is not a solution, I really need to go with lookup tables

Comment: so am I right that "right do be forgotten" = destroying the mechanism of de-cryption of user data?

Comment: I'm not a GDPR expert, so I'm not sure how much indirectly identifiable data about a user that you can retain while still being compliant with GDPR. I am confident that if you destroy the encryption key then you have met your requirement for a user to be forgotten, but you may be able to do less extreme measures and still be compliant.

Comment: Also I believe (but could be wrong) that the right to be forgotten extends to your backups, which means that the lookup table is unlikely to be sufficient as in your backups you still retain the full details. (Assuming you're performing backups and retaining them for a long time)